# Line Chart - Plot range status tagging

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I was doing some research to see if react-chartjs-2 gives you the ability to kind of flag or tag one or more plot points for the purposes of status change within our react application. The scenario is we have a concrete truck that changes the drum rotation speed for mixing concrete while the driver is traveling over a period of time. There are certain points in the changes that the driver performs certain actions such as leaving the plant they pick up the concrete from, arriving at the site to drop the concrete mix and leaving the site. Each status is a flag or tag that we want to indicate on the chart and we have ways to getting each status based on geo tracking. Is there a way to flagging or tagging one or more plot points for those status changes such as "Leave Site (LP)", "Arrive Site (AS)", "Begin Pour (BP)", etc. This is similar to an example mockup we have in the included image.

[Sample Mockup of Flag or Tag Plot Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rctmF.png)

I was researching the documentation and I haven't been able to find the feature to be able to do this.

Comment: You might be able to do that, possibly using [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) and/or [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/). But for more specific help, you'll have to provide a [runnable version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of you code and a more precise description of what and how you want to achieve

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you both, I think the annotation plugin may be the solution for us. This is all theoretical at the moment and haven't attempted anything yet so no code available. However, I will create a new thread if I have any other issues. I appreciate your help!